# Выполнение функции в .NET forms

Tags: c#, winforms, функции

Хочу выполнить функцию DevicesDetect(), я знаю, что объявил её неверно. Windows Forms не позволяет добавить модификаторы private или public к этой функции.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] midiDevices;
        int count = 0;
        //Здесь нужно решение 
        DevicesDetect()
        {
            if (DeviceManager.InputDevices.Count == 0)
            {
                Status.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                Status.Text = "No MIDI devices available";
            }
            else
            {
                Status.ForeColor = Color.Lime;
                Status.Text = "MIDI devices detected";
                foreach (var device in DeviceManager.InputDevices)
                {
                    count++;
                    midiDevices[count] = device.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void RBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DevicesDetect();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private string[] DevicesDetect()
    {
        string[] midiDevices = null;
        if (DeviceManager.InputDevices.Count == 0)
        {
            Status.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            Status.Text = "No MIDI devices available";
        }
        else
        {
            Status.ForeColor = Color.Lime;
            Status.Text = "MIDI devices detected";
            midiDevices = new string[DeviceManager.InputDevices.Count];
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var device in DeviceManager.InputDevices)
            {
                midiDevices[count++] = device.ToString();
            }
        }
        return midiDevices;
    }
```

Comment: Модификатор private недопустим для этого элемента: "private string[] DevicesDetect()"
Я всё равно не могу разобраться почему

Comment: @Sash0l Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо!

Comment: @Sash0l На здоровье. Успехов! Слева от ответа - значок "галочка".